# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Seasoned Advice's [fourth moderator election](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Jolenealaska]

She'll be joining [the existing crew](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank her for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with her as she learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5139903939608576/0).

Comment: Well, that was a nice unambiguous result! :)

Comment: @Marti Yes, but I wish more people had run. FWIW, I think that the "candidate score" was a bit extraneous in this case; the difference in rep was almost insurmountable, so it didn't need to be so amplified by the candidate score.

Comment: Congrats, @Jolenealaska

Comment: Congratulations to @Jolenealaska